# Very slow login on Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu Karmic (alternate i386) on my PC. Everything is working fine, except that after I insert my password at GDM it takes *ages* to get to the desktop (about 16 seconds).
Since I'm using LXDE I'd think login should be quite quick.. Any hint on what I could check?

(the system itself isn't very old.. Pentium Dual-Core E5200 @ 2.50GHz, 2Gb RAM, 2 x 320Gb SATA HDs...)

**Edit:**
Some more info:

- If I logout and then relogin, it still takes 16 seconds to get to the desktop
- top during login says that CPU keeps under 10% usage, and swap isn't touched at all (0Kb used)

Comment: Does the delay happen only when logging in graphically, or does it takes also too long when logging in text mode?

Comment: Text login takes just a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer, but more of a collection of ideas on how to track down your problem. In my experience, these kind of delays happen because of one of the following:

1. Real need for processing lots of stuff.
2. Run out of RAM and use of swap-space.
3. Waiting for a service that either takes time to start, either fails entirely to start (so that the computer waits for the request to time-out).

You could try to investigate more by running on a TTY (ctrl-alt-F2, for example) the programs `top` (show you CPU usage) to rule out #1 and `mem` (shows amount of used memory) to rule out #2. Of course **you should do this while on the graphical console you start your GUI session**.

If it's #3, then you should investigate your logs. You could use [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) as suggested in furtelwart answer (+1) or looking at the logs directly. All relevant logs in ubuntu are under the `/var/log` directory. I use Gnome/GDM and my logs are stored under `/var/log/gdm`. Chances are yours will be under `/val/log/lxde`.

HTH!

Comment: In /var/log/gdm/xsplash-user.log I found a suspicious "** timeout **" line exactly after a pause of 15 seconds.. I think I'll investigate https://bugs.launchpad.net/xsplash/+bug/412455

Comment: That did it :) I uninstalled xsplash and now login-time is down to 3 seconds.. That's the way I like it ;) Many thanks!

Comment: No worries... happy you managed to solve then! :)

Answer (score 4):

Check your [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/). It shows your boot behaviour including login as a PNG graphic and lets your analize possible bottlenecks.

[image: Example from Bootchart.org]

[Large size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpcBI.png)

[Bootchart documentation](http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html)

Comment: I didn't know Bootchart tracks post-login too.. I'll try it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf for invalid localhost entries. Remove them and the problem should fix itself.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, the problem was xsplash having to wait for a timeout... Thanks for your time all the same :)